# InvalidCastException convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linqpad

Basically trying to read in a file and change it from 7 columns to 5 columns and to change the date format as well. Should add that I'm using linqpad and the language is C# statements.

Code:

```
string txtFolderPath = @"D:\Testing\BM\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath, "cplt.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
//files.Dump();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    // reading in csv file
    var csvData = from row in new CpltData(@file, 1000000, 1000000, "") 
    //@"C:\Miu\Blue Fin III - A\Blue Fin III - A\cplt.csv"

    select new
    {
        Period = row.Period,
        IndexEltId = row.IndexEltId,
        EventId = row.EventId,
        Date = row.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"),
        Payout = row.Payout
    };

    //csvData.Dump();

    Util.WriteCsv(csvData, @file);

}
```

> Error message: InvalidCastException Couldn't convert value '8/22/2015
>   1:19:01 AM' to DateTime in row 2

Error occurs on the following line:

> var csvData = from row in new CpltData(@file, 1000000, 1000000, "")

```
CpltData(string csvFilePath, int noOfPeriods, double principal, string currency)
```

It's being imported from some dll, not sure how to access it :/

Comment: Can you show the code for the `CpltData` class?

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Comment: @juharr - see above, also soner please see above

Comment: Whatever `CplData` is, that's where the issue is occurring.  Without knowing more about it we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: you are taking a perfectly fine `DateTime` variable, converting it to string, and then you are trying to assign that string to another `DateTime` variable.  That does not compute.

There is no such thing as a "date format" in a `DateTime` variable.

A  `DateTime` just holds a date, in an internal representation which has absolutely nothing to do with any notion that you might have of years, months, etc.  The "date format" is something that you use when displaying the `DateTime`.

So, just assign your `row.Date` to your `Date` and you are done with this piece of code.

Later, when it is time to display that `Date`, *then* apply a "date format".

Comment: The thing is I need to change it to the correct format, dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss, so that I can compare this excel file with another excel file.

Comment: @user4659009 There is no format there.  It's just a point in time.  The format comes when you write it out in your `Util.WriteCsv` function.

Comment: It looks like a custom error that is generated in the mysterious `CpltData` class.  Who knows how it's trying to parse that file's data into a `DateTime`.

Comment: @KyleW oh, I see, you are probably right. So, in this case, what needs to be modified is probably the cell format of the corresponding column in the excel spreadsheet.  No need to convert any data.